# Imported variables (.mx) are emptied occassionally (Linux, v10.0.2)

Tags: import, memory

I have a severe problem with variables being "emptied" occassionally. I am not able to reproduce the behavior but this is basically what happens:

1) store list `list` obtained from large symbolc computation in file `list.mx` using `Export["list.mx",list]`

2) close the notebook and import the data to another notebook (same machine, same OS etc) using `list=Import["list.mx"]`

Now everything is fine from time to time, in the sense that I can easily work with `list`. However, sometimes I look at `list[[10]]` or any other part of it, the part is displayed and all of a sudden `list` just returns `(* list *)` and moreover also all other previously imported .mx content is deleted as well (although not used at that time). Is there anything wrong with my usage of `Export/Import` or is it a bug? As said, it is not reproducable - but clearly not related to memory being filled up to maximum, yet maybe another memory issue?.

Is there a way to find out what is occasionally going on there?

Comment: What type of processor are you using 32 bit or 64?

Comment: Wild guess: do you have Evaluation -> Notebook's Default Context set to Global or to Unique To ... ?  Make sure to set it to Global and try again.  I haven't experimented with this at all, just a guess.

Comment: @rcollyer 64bit processor (AMD Opteron™ 6176)

Comment: @Szabolcs it is set to Global, so unfortunately no potential cause there

Comment: Apart from Szabolcs's suggestion, it sounds possible that the kernel is crashing. When this occurs, do all symbols become dark blue at the same time and are all other definitions lost as well, or just `list`?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I only noticed that `list` is lost. But since in that particular case there is nothing else than `list` defined when I start the computation it may well be that also other symbols are lost - I can't tell for sure now and will create a dummy symbol before starting the computation; since it is not reproducable it might take some time until I have a result on that specific test. For sure not everything becomes dark blue, so I suspect it is not a kernel crash.

Comment: You may also consider turning off the suggestions bar, if you haven't already. It has some extremely strange interactions with already-defined symbols and can cause them to be cleared in some cases.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Many thanks for that suggestion. I was not aware of those interactions. In fact I have never used the suggestions bar but still have never disabled it. Now it is disabled and I am curious if I see any difference.